# Model for repeated measures design

Tags: mixed-model, anova, repeated-measures

I have measured one continuous variable (muscle density) six times on each subject. The six different measures are taken from 2 different regions of the muscles, each region having three different sites of extraction.
I would like to check if subjects have different values in muscles' density considering age and gender.
I would also like to check if the two regions have different density values.

For instance my data looks like this, where var1 and var2 are two measures of muscle density:

| patient | region | site | var1 | var2 | Age_group | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | region1 | site1 | 35.3 | 3.09 | Young | M |
| 1 | region1 | site2 | 34.3 | 1.87 | Young | M |
| 1 | region1 | site3 | 38.6 | 2.89 | Young | M |
| 1 | region2 | site1 | 40.2 | 4.39 | Young | M |
| 1 | region2 | site2 | 37.3 | 3.91 | Young | M |
| 1 | region2 | site3 | 34.2 | 2.125 | Young | M |
| 2 | region1 | site1 | 34 | 2.28 | Young | F |
| 2 | region1 | site2 | 33.2 | 1.835 | Young | F |
| 2 | region1 | site3 | 33.2 | 1.925 | Young | F |
| 2 | region2 | site1 | 40.5 | 3.25 | Young | F |
| 2 | region2 | site2 | 35 | 1.49 | Young | F |
| 2 | region2 | site3 | 31.4 | 1.13 | Young | F |

I am new to repeated measures design, and I am uncertain if to use a linear mixed model or if mixed ANOVA works fine.